# Bash AWK and Regex Apply on specific Column

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have the following dataset

```
Name,quantity,unit
car,6,6
plane,7,5
ship,2,3.44
bike,8,7.66
```

I want to print only the names which has unit in whole numbers.

I have done the following which does not give out the result

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {
 FS=","
}
/^[0-9]*$/ {
 print "Has Whole numbers: " $1
} 
' file.csv
```

The result should be

```
Has Whole numbers: car
Has Whole numbers: plane
```

Comment: Not worth a separate answer but `/,[0-9]+$/` would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a couple of lines to your test data:

```
Name,quantity,unit
car,6,6
plane,7,5
ship,2,3.44
bike,8,7.66
Starship,1,1.0
Super Heavy,2,0
null,0,
```

And awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'int($3)==$3 ""' file
```

Output:

```
car,6,6
plane,7,5
Super Heavy,2,0
```

`int($3)` makes an integer of `$3` and `$3 ""` turns `$3` to a string.

Comment: Clever solution

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `/^[0-9]*$/` to `$3 ~ /^[0-9]*$/ && $3 != 0` once in your tried attempt it should work then.

In case you DO NOT want to hard code field number and want to find out unit field number automatically then try following.

```
awk -F="," -v field_val="unit"  '
FNR==1{
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    if($j==field_val){
       field_number=j
       next
    }
  }
}
$field_number ~ /[0-9]*$/ && $field_number!=0{
    print "Has whole numbers: " $1
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: it does work partially. It prints null values as well. Whats the use of ~

Comment: @Hailey, sure added that condition, please do check my generic solution too where you need not to hard code your field number it will get it automatically lemme know how it goes here?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, wrap the code inside  a pair of  ````

Comment: @Mihir, thanks buddy but I tried and it is not showing it still in correct format.

Comment: You need to enter a newline after opening ``` and a newline before closing ```

Comment: @EdMorton, Ed sir how about now? Thanks to you and Mihir learnt new thing on SO.

Comment: @EdMorton, could not live without coding on SO :) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure 3rd column is a number:

```
awk -F, '(NR != 1 && $3 !~ /\./){print "Has Whole numbers:", $1}' file.csv
```

or well actually its better the way you did it:

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /^[0-9]$/{print "Has Whole numbers:", $1}' file
```